# Why does here use a present "find"?

Tags: tense, present-tense

[Missing 13-year-old Jayme Closs found alive in Wisconsin](https://www.cnn.com/2019/01/10/us/jayme-closs-missing-wisconsin-girl-found/index.html)

> "And I just shut myself totally down. I thought today was going to be
>   the day, and then I **find** out two hours later that she’s found and
>   I just cannot believe this."

Two hours later was just "now"?

Comment: No, it was in the past, she the talker just switched to so-called [narrative present](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/154648/2127). We sometimes use the present tense to speak of past events.

Comment: @CowperKettle That excellent comment would make an even better answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it was in the past, the talker just switched to so-called [narrative present](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/154648/2127). We sometimes use the present tense to speak of past events.